# Contactform model displays no content in the Django admin panel. Django admin panel module values are empty

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-admin

so I am trying to make an simple contact form for my website and Technically I am finished with this.

But whenever i try to test and submit something through this form, the input values are not showing in the admin panel.

I get no errors but the i don't see any code

For example:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/plMjM.png)
This should add 3 values into the admin panel

But instead (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQR7U.png)
does it add nothing into the admin panel.

The code should work like this:

1. The user should write a message in the HTML.

```
<section class="contact-me">
              <h2>Kontaktiere mich</h2>
              <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <h4>Vorname:</h4>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Vorname" name="vorname">
                <h4>Email:</h4>
                <input type="email" placeholder="email@email.com" name="email">
                <h4>Nachicht/Frage:</h4>
                <textarea name="nachricht" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> <br>
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
              </form>
            </section>
```

2. In the views.py file there is this code witch should take the inputs and convert them into the model.

views.py

```
def aboutme(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        contact = ContactForm()
        vorname = request.POST["vorname"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        nachricht = request.POST["nachricht"]

        contact.name = vorname
        contact.email = email
        contact.nachricht = nachricht

        contact.save()
        return HttpResponse("<h1>Danke für deine Nachricht</h1>")
    return render(request, "aboutme.html")
```

models.py

```
class ContactForm(models.Model):
    vorname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=20)
    nachricht = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vorname
```

The admin panel shows that there is an entry but it doesn't show the inputs ?

Does anyone have an clue why this is ?

I think it doesn't have anython to do with the HTML or the views.py i think that it has something to do with the model itself but i dont know.

Please help me if you have time.

Comment: why is ContactForm inheriting from models.Model, it should be inheriting from forms.Form or forms.ModelForm

Answer (score 1):

edit your views.py, you have to send request.POST into your ContactForm():

```
def aboutme(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        contact = ContactForm(request.POST)  #
        vorname = request.POST["vorname"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        nachricht = request.POST["nachricht"]

        contact.name = vorname
        contact.email = email
        contact.nachricht = nachricht

        contact.save()
        return HttpResponse("<h1>Danke für deine Nachricht</h1>")
    return render(request, "aboutme.html")
```

but if your ContactForm is look like this:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    vorname = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    nachricht = forms.CharField()
```

your view should be like this, short and simple:

```
def aboutme(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        contact = ContactForm(request.POST)
        contact.save()
        return HttpResponse("<h1>Danke für deine Nachricht</h1>")
    return render(request, "aboutme.html")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response it took a big step further i think, but when i make the changes you suggest i get an error:  TypeError: 'DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass' object is not iterable.            I have made some research about this error, but i don't know to much about forms.

Comment: You can print(request.POST["email"]

Comment: write print(request.POST["email"]) in your view and see are you receiving anything?check the terminal

Comment: Hey, so i added the print function and it gave me the input email in the terminal. I then added a print function which prints(contact.email). This also printed the right email.  But when i try to print(ContactForm.email) it prints this: <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000001E4BA2558D0>         I don't know if its the way i try to print this or if this really is the error. But i am now very sure that the problem is either in the model or in the way the admin panel recieves the inputs.  Also thank you for your replies.